# iOS Developer Enterprise Program

Tags: ios

I'm looking for additional information which I can't find on apple's website:

- Does the App get reviewed by Apple?
- How exactly can I get the App to the employees? Do I send a link to the App or is there some authentification needed?
- Do I need to register everyone's Device ID who wants to use this app?

The thing is, that we develop an app which will be used by a small group of people and our App probably won't make it through the review process, since we use a proprietary API.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How small is that group?

Comment: Now the enterprise account is not good to apply, many people do not have this kind of account, you can look at this website,https://www.iosenterpriseaccount.com/, 
the enterprise program in principle can let a lot of people(no limit) inside the company to use, while the iOS developer program can be published to the public.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. No, the app doesn't get reviewed by Apple
2. You can just send a link to the app, the instructions at http://shinydevelopment.com/blog/over-the-air-ios-provisioning-and-distribution/ should work fine for enterprise distribution, just make sure that you select your enterprise provisioning profile
3. No, there's no need to register device UUIDs

Comment: Thanks dude. helped me a lot. really no need to register UDIDs?

Can I use production certificate and distribution profile without goping for development .cer and profiles, as i am running out of time. 

Any help is appreciated ?? Thanks

Comment: How many maximum numbers of user can test app? Is there any limit?