# What are the requirements for distributing an internal iOS app via the Enterprise Program?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I'm in charge of developing an application for my company. It'll only be used by my company. I found the Enterprise Program.
I read 
[iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825686/ios-developer-enterprise-program)
but I also read something about MDM iOS that I need to implement.

Is MDM needed to distribute my app?  Also, how will my coworkers be able to download the app? How does Apple know they are authorized, and not some random guy who found the link on Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to do MDM for the enterprise program as far as I know. As for preventing people from downloading the app, I think you just have to keep the link private, or put it behind a URL that can only be accessed on your company network or VPN. And of course, require login, so someone can’t access your internal information just by downloading the app! Presumably, Apple will revoke your enterprise privileges if they find you are abusing them.

Source: I worked at a company that used enterprise distribution for internal beta distribution, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

One of my clients has 30 iPads that are used with an in-house developed app.  The "Ad Hoc" distribution model is easy to implement if the number of deployed devices is less than 100. This approach is sometimes described as a "Beta test" approach, but that's just one common use for it.

See these pages:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

[Ad-hoc Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081180/ad-hoc-deployment)